# Reading XML file from specified starting position

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, lambda, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I have an XML file that is constantly being appended to. I need to read in the data from the XML repeatedly, but on each pass I do not want to retrieve data that I have processed in the previous run.

Since I know how long the file is at the time of processing, I figure I could use the length of the file (minus the ending /Contacts tag) to determine where I last left off. Knowing this, what is the best way to retrieve all of the Contact tags starting from a particular byte position within the file?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Contacts>
    <Contact>
      <Name>Todd</Name>
      <Email>todd@blah.com</Email>
  </Contact>
    <Contact>
      <Name>Sarah</Name>
      <Email>sarah@blah.com</Email>
  </Contact>
</Contacts>
```

This block of code grabs all of the contacts. I would like to limit it so it only picks up data after the first contact (at byte 116.)

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(PATH_TO_FILE);
var contact = xdoc.Descendants("Contact").Select(x => (string)x).ToArray();
```

Comment: just out of curiosity: why don't you use a database for this?

Comment: The XML is the output of a vendor's product which I cannot change. The request is to generate a near-real-time method of parsing these XML files and then process the data within it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to save/retrieve by index position. This will work just as well.

```
int position = 1;
var contacts = xdoc
    .Descendants("Contact")
    .Select((x, index) => new { Contact = x, Index = index })
    .Where(x => x.Index >= position)
    .Select(x => x.Contact);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you still want to read from specific offset and keep yourself on high-level. Here is XmlTailReader that puts content of document which have only end-ing tag in other root element:

```
class XmlTailReader : XmlReader
{
    private readonly XmlReader _reader;
    private readonly XmlReader _fakeReader;
    private int _level;
    enum Fake { Start, Align, None, End };
    private Fake _fake;

    public XmlTailReader(XmlReader reader, string rootTag = "root")
    {
        _reader = reader;
        _fake = Fake.Start;

        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        var root = doc.CreateElement(rootTag);
        doc.AppendChild(root);
        // make sure that we'll get Element/EndElement
        root.AppendChild(doc.CreateComment("dummy")); 
        _fakeReader = new XmlNodeReader(root);
    }

    private XmlReader Proxy
    {
        get
        {
            switch(_fake)
            {
            case Fake.Start:
            case Fake.Align:
            case Fake.End:
                return _fakeReader;
            default:
                return _reader;
            }
        }
    }

    public override bool Read()
    {
        switch(_fake)
        {
        case Fake.Start:
            if (!_fakeReader.Read()) return false;
            if (NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                ++_level;
                _fake = Fake.Align;
            }
            return true;
        case Fake.Align:
            _fake = Fake.None;
            while(true) // align to first Element
            {
                if (!_reader.Read()) return false;
                if (NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    ++_level;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return true;
        case Fake.None:
            try
            {
                if (!_reader.Read()) return false;
            }
            catch (XmlException e)
            {
                // if (!e.Message.StartsWith("Unexpected end tag.")) throw;
                // reading of extra-closing tag cause "Unexpected end tag"
                // so use this as event for transition too
                _fake = Fake.End;
                if (!_fakeReader.Read()) return false;
                return true;
            }
            switch(NodeType)
            {
            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                ++_level;
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                if (--_level == 0)
                {
                    _fake = Fake.End;
                    if (!_fakeReader.Read()) return false;
                }
                break;
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return Proxy.Read();
        }
    }

    public override string Value
    {
        get { return Proxy.Value; }
    }

    public override XmlNodeType NodeType
    {
        get { return Proxy.NodeType; }
    }
    // rest use Proxy property for forwarding
}

void Main()
{
    var xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + @"
<Contacts>
    <Contact>
      <Name>Todd</Name>
      <Email>todd@blah.com</Email>
  </Contact>
    <Contact>
      <Name>Sarah</Name>
      <Email>sarah@blah.com</Email>
  </Contact>
    <Contact>
      <Name>Peter</Name>
      <Email>peter@blah.com</Email>
  </Contact>
</Contacts>";
    const string tag = "</Contact>";
    var xml2 = xml.Substring(xml.IndexOf(tag) + tag.Length);
    using(var sr = new StringReader(xml2))
    using(var xr = XmlReader.Create(sr, new XmlReaderSettings { ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment, } ))
    using(var xr2 = new XmlTailReader(xr, "xxx"))
    {
        var xdoc = XDocument.Load(xr2);
        xdoc.Descendants("Contact").Dump();
    }
}
```

Note that ConformanceLevel should be Fragment for such kind of reading.

Answer (score 1):

You can create tricky Stream, that emulates Ducument's start element at the custom position.
Its very rough code, but its working

```
void Main()
{
 var xml =
    @"<Contacts><Contact><Name>Todd</Name><Email>todd@blah.com</Email></Contact><Contact>
      <Name>Sarah1</Name>
      <Email>sarah@blah.com</Email>
  </Contact>
  <Contact>
      <Name>Sarah2</Name>
      <Email>sarah@blah.com</Email>
  </Contact>
</Contacts>";

    var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml));
    ms.Position = 74;
    var reader = XmlReader.Create(new CustomReader("<Contacts>",ms));

    var xdoc = XDocument.Load(reader);
    var contact = xdoc.Descendants("Contact").Select(x => x).ToArray();

    contact.Dump();
}

public class CustomReader : Stream
{
    private readonly string _element;
    private readonly Stream _stream;
    private int _offset;

    public CustomReader(string element, Stream stream)
    {
        _element = element;
        _stream = stream;
        _offset = -element.Length;
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override bool CanSeek
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void Close()
    {
        _stream.Close();
        base.Close();
    }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override long Length
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public override long Position
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        if (count == 0) return 0;

        if (_offset < 0)
        {
            var buf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_element);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(buf, 0, buffer, offset, buf.Length);
            _offset = 0;
            return buf.Length;
        }

        return _stream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to break consistency of reading XML. You cant avoid building `XDocument` with some first elements with something like:

```
class XmlSkipReader : XmlReader
{
    private readonly XmlReader _reader;
    private readonly int _skip;
    private int _level, _skipped;
    public XmlSkipReader(XmlReader reader, int skip)
    {
        _reader = reader;
        _skip = skip;
    }

    public override bool Read()
    {
        if (_skipped == _skip) return _reader.Read();
        if (_level < 1)
        {
            if(!_reader.Read()) return false;
            switch(_reader.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element: ++_level; break;
            }
            return true;
        }
        if(!_reader.Read()) return false;
        switch(_reader.NodeType)
        {
            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                ++_level;
                break;
            default: return true;
        }

        for(; _skipped < _skip; ++_skipped)
        {
            while(_level > 1)
            {
                if(!_reader.Read()) return false;
                switch(_reader.NodeType)
                {
                    case XmlNodeType.Element:
                        ++_level;
                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                        --_level;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        return _reader.Read();
    }
    // rest is just proxy to _reader
}

void Main()
{
    var xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + @"
<Contacts>
    <Contact>
      <Name>Todd</Name>
      <Email>todd@blah.com</Email>
  </Contact>
    <Contact>
      <Name>Sarah</Name>
      <Email>sarah@blah.com</Email>
  </Contact>
</Contacts>";
    using(var sr = new StringReader(xml))
    using(var xr = XmlReader.Create(sr))
    using(var xr2 = new XmlSkipReader(xr, 1))
    {
        var xdoc = XDocument.Load(xr2);
        xdoc.Descendants("Contact").Dump();
    }
}
```